# Can someone recomend compatible Road/Lever shifters to drive a Shimano Deore RD-M5020-SGS, Shadow Plus, 10 Speed rear mech

Tags: mountain-bike, shifter, upgrades, conversion, gravel

I have a Whyte 429 with the Deore SL-M4010, 10 Speed driving the Shimano Deore RD-M5020-SGS, Shadow Plus, 10 Speed rear mech.

I want to put Gravel (Drop) bars on it because I simply find it so much more comfortable with that style.

I regularly ride my Jamis Bosanova for gravel, which I've added Schwalbe GK's 43mm Front and 35mm rear, however that only gives clearance for good weather days. Dont have the budget to buy a Gravel bike for the clearance, hence the desire to put the drop bars on my 429.

I'd be eternally grateful for recommendations.

Comment: Alternatively, a solution to upgrade i.e. a compatible Gravel set for Shifter and rear mech for a 1x10 that retains the cassette

Comment: If you wish to use a Shimano road (gravel) drop bar shifter/brifter on a ten-speed MTB rear derailleur you will likely need a cable ratio-converting device like the Wolfstooth Tanpan device (I used one of these for an 11-speed setup - Ultegra 8000 series shifters with an 11-speed Shimano XT SGS MTB RD - can't recall the model).

Answer (score 1):

This question is really about what your plans are for your brakes and whether bar-end shifters are acceptable to you. The bike has Tektro hydros. You could do the Hylex + Microshift Shimano Mountain 10 bar end combination. That is in many ways the most direct path that uses the largest number of things you already have. Hylex levers aren't particularly cheap and getting them as lever-only can require jumping through some hoops, and there's a threat of false economy because you're very possibly buying hoses anyway, which come at a better value in set form. That's the only path that involves re-using your brakes. Everything else doesn't, and at that point the economy of re-using your RD is just another piece of the puzzle. (The premise here being that Tektro hydro brakes are basically incompatible with any brifter - some will tell you otherwise but I'd disagree for safety's personally).

All the paths that involve STIs have you changing your brakes and either adapting the pull for the RD or replacing it. Considering the bike, there's probably not much economy there.

Comment: Hi Nathan, than you for your very detailed answer. Would it be possible to instead install a matching shifters and rear derailleur and then retain the tektro brakes?

Comment: @Iain unless you are willing to do hacky things and accept the cost/consequences if it doesn't work, you should regard the calipers you have as only being compatible with Tektro/TRP levers, and the only hydro ones of those are the Hylex levers. Personally if you want to do any of this on anything like an appropriate budget, I might look hard at just going to one of the various bars out there now that take the controls you have but have some characteristics of drop bars, the Surly Corner Bar being an example.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, I’ll look in to that